# ASP.NET Listview->Click Row->Perform action

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, listview, linq-to-sql

I need some help with the following.

I have a list view that I fill with code-behind:

Linq->Sql:

```
        ListView1.DataSource = from x in database.ITEMS
                               select x;
        ListView1.DataBind();
```

Content of ITEMS:

- ID
- Name
- Quantity

I only show the name of the fields:

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Assuming I have 25 rows in the database, I fill the list view with 25 rows. Next is what I need help with. The user needs to click one of the 25 names (complete row) and redirects to a page where the content of that row is showed. So lets say someone clicks on "Cars", he'll be redirected and he will see: You have selected Cars, Cars has an ID of 19 and a Quantity of 6.

I have browsed the Internet already but I am having trouble finding solutions that I can understand. I am kind of a noob when it comes to list views and other data displaying methods.

My 2 questions:

1. **How do I start a event when I click a row (and not a button or a link in that row)?**
2. **When I click a row and start a event, how can I check which one was clicked?**

I hope someone can explain to me how this is done in a user friendly noob kind of way or redirect me to a tutorial discussing my issue's and also in a user friendly way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I am not sure if this is the best way to go with this (I'll be interested what other think)... but this will work .

Update your listview to something like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // simple redirect to your detail page, passing the selected ID 
            function redir(id) {
                window.location.href = "mydetailpage.aspx?id=" + id;
            }
        </script>
        <table>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr onclick="redir('<%# Eval("ID") %>');">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </table>
```

Then create another page to show your detail (e.g. mydetailpage.aspx) - this should requery your database and show the other fields, given the id passed in the querystring.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click the name.

Comment: Sorry - please see edit. You need to add a dummy linkbutton to include the appropriate js resource

Comment: Okay I can "fire" the event but the if statement returns false because __EVENTARGUMENT is not equal to row. The statement is always false and therefore does not enter the event and "perform" the code that is inside of it. I cannot see why that is, do you know why it is doing that?

Comment: Ok I have simplified to use a JS function. No need to do an ASP.NET postback here. You can remove the code that handles _EVENTTARGET in your code behind... hope that works for you ;)

Comment: Thanks, this does work for me. However, I am wondering, is this a safe way to do. If a user changes the id in the URL, will that user be redirected to a page that he or she does not has privileges to?

Comment: You should do whatever security you need on the mydetailpage itself. Never trust what is sent by the client!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41599/discussion-between-niek-jonkman-and-geedubb)

Answer (score 1):

you can define onclick attribute to call javascript function on tr element like this :

```
onclick="yourfunction('<%# Eval("Name") %>');"
```

Then you can put anything in your javascript function like redirect to another page