# RowClick in ASP.NET ListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView which renders a table, like this:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lwPerson">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/blabla/blabla.png" alt="New person"/></td>
                <td><strong>New person</strong></td>
                <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandName="NewPerson" ImageUrl="~/blabla/icon_arrow.png"></asp:ImageButton></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><img src='<%# IIf(Not Eval("PlayerPerson.User.SmallProfileThumbnailPath") Is Nothing, Eval("PlayerPerson.User.SmallProfileThumbnailPath"), "/blabla/default_profilepic.png")  %>' alt="Profile picture" /></td>
            <td><%# Eval("PlayerPerson.Name") %></td>
            <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandName="ExistingPerson" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PlayerPerson.PersonId") %>' ImageUrl="~/blabla/icon_arrow.png"></asp:ImageButton></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

To this I would like to add a click event to the whole TableRow, which should act exactly like the ImageButton. It would be easy, if I could just fire the ItemCommand event of the ListView, just the same way as I do with the button - but I have not found a solution to do this directly. Instead I added an onclick-event (client):

```
<tr onclick="test(this);">
```

This will fire a JavaScript function:

```
function test(tr) {
    tr.cells[2].firstElementChild.click();
}
```

I know that there are only 3 columns in my table, and I also know that there is only one element in that column. Then I just fire the click event of the button. This works, but is probably not the prettiest solution.

So, I would appreciate if anyone can tell me if there is another (and better) approach to do this. Also I would like to know how to 'optimize' the JavaScript function - maybe written in jQuery instead.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098257/asp-net-listview-click-row-perform-action

Comment: The method you mention is equal to my own approach. Maybe I explained me wrong, but it´s the Javascript/jQuery thing I am asking about - how to get the ImageButton element in the ListView by jQuery in the 'best practice' way.

Comment: Or even better how to fire the ItemCommand event like when clicking the ImageButton.