# Adding a click event to a Hyperlink displayed in ListView VB.NET ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to add a click event to a Hyperlink tag that's render in ListView?
Basically, I have a HyperLink tag that generates a link dynamically and it opens up to a new tab when users click on it. At the same time, when the user click on it, I want to post a text or make the text label visible. Sample code below:

```
<asp:ListView ...>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Msg" Text="*You have already accessed this link*" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="label1" NavigatUrl='<%#Eval("Link")%>'Target="_blink" text="Click Link" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
  <//ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098257/asp-net-listview-click-row-perform-action ... search next time... alot of topics about it.

Comment: That doesn't work. He's redirecting the page with javascript and not staying on the same page. In addition, he's not using hyperlink tag to move from pages. I don't want to move from pages, just open up a new tab. You can't open up a new tab with javascript because browser blocks pop-up.

Comment: one of 1000 answers I found. pasted first. but maybe you did search and it's some other case... sorry for that comment then.

Comment: You could use a linkbutton instead of a hyperlink, then use the command argument to get your eval link.  Use the on_click event to do whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QueryString. Add the link with a Query Parameter on it and then -

```
If IsPostBack=True then 'Check if the page is reloading [Because when you clik on the link with the same link, it will reload the page]
'Considering the QueryString will be like - "yourdomain/default.aspx?item=1"
'Check for QueryString
Dim s_ItemId As String = Request.QueryString("item")

if s_ItemId<>"" then
'Do whatever you want    
End If
```